# How to count number of employees within a department of that given month?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So my question is this, lets say we have a table that has, Name, Department, Month, and I want to know how many people are in that Department of that given Month. I've tried a few different variations of COUNTIF, COUNTIFS, SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF, etc. but can't quite get it. To show an example of it:

```
NAME   |  DEPARTMENT  |  MONTH
JOHN   |      A       |  FEBRUARY
DAVID  |      A       |  FEBRUARY
STEPH  |      B       |  FEBRUARY
MIKE   |      B       |  FEBRUARY
JOHN   |      B       |  MARCH
DAVID  |      A       |  MARCH
STEPH  |      A       |  MARCH
MIKE   |      A       |  MARCH
```

I would like the results to show as:

```
# Of People    DEPARTMENT   MONTH
   2         |    A      | FEBRUARY
   2         |    B      | FEBRUARY
   3         |    A      | MARCH
   1         |    B      | MARCH
```

How would I be able to do this within excel? I've tried multiple different formulas but so far no luck, so any help would be much appreciated!

Please let me know if anything needs to be further clarified.

EDIT:
The formula I used is:

```
=COUNTIFS($C:$C,G$3,$B:$B,$F4)
G3 = February
F4 = Department 'A'
```

Which works to count all values, but this question came up after I posted this and tested it out. Let's say you have the same name in the same department and month, for example:

```
NAME  |  DEPARTMENT  |  MONTH
JOHN  |       A      |  FEBRUARY
JOHN  |       A      |  FEBRUARY
MIKE  |       B      |  FEBRUARY
MIKE  |       B      |  FEBRUARY
```

With the COUNTIFS statement above it would look like:

```
# OF People  |  DEPARTMENT  |  MONTH
     2       |      A       | FEBRUARY
     2       |      B       | FEBRUARY
```

Is it possible to put something in addition to the COUNTIFS to automatically combine duplicates? So instead of the answer up above it would show up as:

```
# OF People  |  DEPARTMENT  |  MONTH
     1       |       A      | FEBRUARY
     1       |       B      | FEBRUARY
```

This is the result I would want, counting the names as a unique value instead of duplicating the names.

Again please let me know if anything else needs to be clarified!

Comment: What was your COUNTIFS attempt?

Comment: This should be just a COUNTIFS, so not sure why that wasn't working. Please share your formula and the error/wrong result you are getting?

Comment: As has been said - COUNTIFS should work.  Is the month just entered as text, or is it a real date formatted to show just the month (it says _February_ in the cell, but the formula bar says something like _28/02/2018_)?

Comment: The COUNTIFS statement that I used is the following:
`=COUNTIFS($C:$C,G$3,$B:$B,$F6)`
G3 = February
F6 = Department
This does give the count, but what I'm wondering is, is there a way to get Unique values, for example if JOHN appears 5 times in department A in February, I want to count as only 1 for JOHN instead of 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

```
=COUNTIFS([Range1],[Criteria1],[Range2],[Criteria2])
```

This is also a situation where you could use a Pivot Table, setting DEPARTMENT and MONTH as rows, and NAME as values with a count calculation.